# How to force absolute uri kind for returnUrl in ASP.NET Core login redirects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I use this config for my auth operations

```
.AddCookie(SchemeName, c =>
{
    c.LoginPath = "/login";
    c.LogoutPath = "/login/logout";
    c.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    c.ExpireTimeSpan = CookieLifetime;
})
```

It works fine and redirects to my LoginController Index method when needed and passes returnUrl parameter of page caused redirect as well, but this returnUrl parameter is relative. How can I force ASP.NET Core to pass absolute url instead?

Comment: Using absolute URIs here can open up a security risk, where your user could be redirected to a web-site that doesn't belong to you, yet under the impression that it does.

Comment: Yes, I know it. We have layer of protection against this later in the code. But thanks for mention it!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with this code, but I am not sure that this is a good approach

```
c.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
{
    var uri = new Uri(context.RedirectUri);
    var ru = $"{uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)}?returnUrl={context.Request.GetEncodedUrl()}";
    context.Response.Redirect(ru); 
    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```